# IntellijIDEA - PluginClassLoader : ClassNotFoundException after moving class to another package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for AndroidStudio .
Assume my package name is `com.name.app`

I have a class `ApiHelper` which has a `ResponseHandler` interface. Another class, `ButtonActionHandler` (extends `AnAction`) implements `ResponseHandler` from `ApiHelper`.

Everything works fine at this point. But if I move `ApiHelper` to `com.name.app.helpers` package I get NoClassDefFoundError &  PluginClassLoader - ClassNotFoundException.

Any idea why this is happening after moving moving file to another package?

Comment: Did you make sure your class isn't referenced by its old fully qualified name in `plugin.xml`?

Comment: I moved only `ApiHelper` to `com.name.app.helper`. It is not referenced from `plugin.xml`. `ButtonActionHandler` is still inside `com.name.app` and its reference inside `plugin.xml` is correct.

Comment: Have you tried a clean build? Are you sure `ApiHelper` is not referenced by its old FQN in a string or an XML file somewhere?

Comment: Clean build did not work. Old FQN is not used. I extracted my interface from `ApiHelper` class into it's own class, placed it inside `com.name.app` (same package as `ButtonActionHandler`) and its working. It also works if I move the interface to `com.newname.helper`. But if both `ApiHelper` and `ResponseHandler` are placed inside same package, this error occurs.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the issue on a new project so I just Invalidated cache and restarted intellij and its working. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalidate cache and restart. It worked.